# replace extension in string

Tags: regex, text

I have text file that has the following strings:

```
coordsys = "Z:/SatData/Satimages/Project/Mtsat/mtsat-2r/nrl/NW-Pacific/Geo-Color/Project/201108170432_DAY1.jp2"
coordsys = "Z:/SatData/Satimages/Project/Mtsat/mtsat-2r/nrl/NE-Pacific/Geo-Color/Project/201208170432_NGT1.jp2"
coordsys = "Z:/SatData/Satimages/Project/kalpana/images/Geo-Color/Project/201108170432_DAY1.jp2"
img = ".jp2"
```

I need to change extension from jp2 to img only in strings that started with "coordsys", but not any other. For example img = ".jp2" should stay img = ".jp2", but all of others string should become to:

```
coordsys = "Z:/SatData/Satimages/Project/Mtsat/mtsat-2r/nrl/NW-Pacific/Geo-Color/Project/201108170432_DAY1.img"
coordsys = "Z:/SatData/Satimages/Project/Mtsat/mtsat-2r/nrl/NE-Pacific/Geo-Color/Project/201208170432_NGT1.img"
coordsys = "Z:/SatData/Satimages/Project/kalpana/images/Geo-Color/Project/201108170432_DAY1.img"
```

How can I do this with regexp?

Comment: `:g/^coordsys/s/\.jp2"$/.img"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace all `(coordsys)(.*)(\.jp2)` with `$1$2.img`